# Conflict with libjpeg using Qt and OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, conflict

I have a VS2010 project using static linked **Qt 4.8.4** and **OpenCV 2.4.4** libraries. Both of them include **libjpeg** but in different versions. What should I do to avoid the version conflict at the following lines?

```
/* Guard against version mismatches between library and caller. */
cinfo->mem = NULL;      /* so jpeg_destroy knows mem mgr not called */
if (version != JPEG_LIB_VERSION) // <-------------- this line
  ERREXIT2(cinfo, JERR_BAD_LIB_VERSION, JPEG_LIB_VERSION, version);
if (structsize != SIZEOF(struct jpeg_decompress_struct))
  ERREXIT2(cinfo, JERR_BAD_STRUCT_SIZE, 
     (int) SIZEOF(struct jpeg_decompress_struct), (int) structsize);
```

`version` is 62 while `JPEG_LIB_VERSION` is 80. I know the issue is related to linking, so I guess there could be a way to specify which libjpeg must be used.

Comment: If the only problem is wrong `JPEG_LIB_VERSION` value then this is not related to linking because this value is simply specified in a header file. You need to find out where is it defined and where this file comes from.